# How to load a huge CSV to a Pyspark DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load a huge genomic dataset (2504 lines and 14848614 columns) to a PySpark DataFrame, but no success. I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I thought the main idea of using spark was exactly the independency of memory... (I'm newbie on it. Please, bear with me :)

This is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "6G").getOrCreate()

file_location = "1kGp3_chr3_6_10.raw"
file_type = "csv"

infer_schema = "true"
first_row_is_header = "true"
delimiter = "\t"
max_cols = 15000000 # 14848614 variants loaded

data = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .option("maxColumns", max_cols) \
  .load(file_location)
```

I know we can set the `StorageLevel` by, for example `df.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)`, but this is possible only after you successfully load the file to a DataFrame, isn't it? (not sure if I missing something)

Here's the error:

```
...
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o33.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...
```

Thanks!

---

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
I forgot to mention the size of the CSV: 70G.

Here's another attempt which resulted in a different error: 
I tried with a smaller dataset (2504 lines and 3992219 columns. File size: 19G), and increased memory to `"spark.driver.memory", "12G"`.
After about 35 min running the load method, I got:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o33.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 54 tasks (1033.1 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
```

Comment: try increasing the "spark.driver.memory" to a value much greater than "6G".

Comment: In general Spark SQL is not suitable for usage with very wide schemas as you have here. It is not clear what is your exact goal here, but you should probably use one of the dedicated tools (I guess [avocado](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/avocado)) or non-spark tools that can handle other modes of scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is telling you the problem - you don't have enough memory.

The value in using pyspark is not the independency of memory but it's speed because (it uses ram), the ability to have certain data or operations persist, and the ability to leverage multiple machines.

So, solutions -

1) If possible devote more ram.

2) Depending on the size of your CSV file, you may or may not be able to fit it into memory for a laptop or desktop. If that case, you may need to put this into something like a cloud instance for reasons of speed or cost. Even there you may not find a machine large enough to fit the whole thing in memory for a single machine (though to be frank that would be pretty large considering Amazon's current max for a single memory-optimized (u-24tb1.metal) instance is 24,576 GiB.

And there you see the true power of pyspark: the ability to load truly giant datasets into ram and run it across multiple machines.